# batch - Reading lines/var from config file without for command

Tags: batch-file

Can you read lines from a config/txt file without the `for /f` or any `for`?
Anyways, I wanted to have a config file what determines the color of the prompt. 
I have the following batch code:

```
@echo OFF
color %color%
@echo
cmd
```

and this .config file:

```
---------type color here----------
a
```

Expected output:

```
color a
```

And,

```
set /p color<main.config
```

Only reads the first line of the file.

Comment: Why not? What's wrong with using them?

Comment: It's possible with `set /p`, but it's far easier to use a for loop. Why don't you want to use one?

Comment: When you look at the help for the colour command, `Color /?` it clearly shows that you provide both a background and foreground colours. Whilst you can just provide one, _as in your example_, you have no way of determining it's compatibility with the other. If the end user has already set their background colour to green, then setting the foreground to the same would not do as you intended, they may also have a background which wasn't green but reading a green font on it would be visually difficult. For the sake of one character, I find your approach completely unwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you have your files 1.bat (your batch) and 1.config (configfile) 
you can do this if you really dont want to use the for command.

```
@echo OFF
findstr /V "#" 1.config >1.tmpcfg
set /p COL= < 1.tmpcfg
del 1.tmpcfg
color %COL%
cmd
```

But I'd prefer using 'for'...
:-)

Comment: can you explain what you are doing? with the `<` because I don't understand. I only understand `>>`

Comment: @Stephan What about the `'#'` Is that a # like, put something in?

Comment: @Sam : findstr is writing the 'a' to a new file '1.tmpcfg' since the line contains no '#'.
Then the input of 1.tmpcfg is used to pass the content of the file (here 'a') to the set /p command. 
'<' passes the content of a file to a command...

Comment: @Sam it's the string to search for to exclude (`/v`)  that line. See [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Comment: @ChristianNagel you say you prefer for.... Can you give an example of `for` with parameters? and how parameters work? And if you can set parameters? I wanted to know if it works without `for` because I dont know how parameters work

Answer (score 4):

It's so easy with a `for`:

```
for /f "eol=-" %%a in (1.config) do color %%a
```

assuming your config file is like:

```
---------type color here----------
a
```

I'd recommend to change your config file a bit (so more than one value can be stored):

```
---------type color here----------
foreground=e
background=1
```

and read it with:

```
for /f "eol=- delims=" %%a in (1.config) do set "%%a"
color %background%%foreground%
```

Learn more about [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html). It's the most powerful command in batch and worth every minute you spend learning it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what do parameters like ‘%%a’ do exactly?

Comment: It's a variable. Here, with each run of the loop, it contains the next line of the textfile (in other cases it can hold part of the line(s); depends on tokens and delims).