# Batch file how to use findstr command to find a text and make it a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I want to know how to use Findstr command to find a text in a file and make it a variable here what i tried :

```bat
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /m "100" Config.dat') do set "Variable=%%a"
cls 
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
goto found
) else (
goto nope
)
:found
cls
echo founded ! %Variable%
pause
exit
:nope
cls
echo not found!
pause
exit
```

Ok i explain : In the 2nd line the number "100" is what i want to find and the "Config.dat" is the file that have in it the number 100 and some other numbers and the "Variable" in there is the name of the variable that i want to store in it 100.

The problem is when it founded number 100 it goes to the function "found" and displays "Founded! 100" but when it not founded it also goes to "found" function and only display founded! without 100. So why when it didn't founded it it goes to "found" i need it to go to "nope".

So i hope you guys explain to me if i did something wrong and thanks!

Comment: To start with, you need to remove the `/m` option on your `findstr` command. There's also no need for the `/I` option, as the number has no case. And because you already know the number, there's no need to put your command inside a `for` loop at all.

Comment: But if i removed `for` do it will affect the Variable ? (It will not store the "100" or the number in the variable)

Comment: You just have to use `Set "Variable=100"`!

Comment: show your config file (at least the first - let's say - three lines.

Comment: I know i can make a file with only the number "100" and use a command like this : `echo 100 >File.dat`#`set /p Var=<File.dat` but i want to make one file that hold all the config of the program

Comment: something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48607279/2152082)?

Comment: Exactly! holding more than one value in one file Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is because `for /F` calls command in a standalone `cmd.exe` process and does not return the error level into context of the caller:

```
@echo off

rem drop last error level
type nul>nul

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`cmd.exe /C @exit /b 123`) do rem
echo ERRORLEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

-

```
ERRORLEVEL=0
```

If you want just load config values into environment variables, then there is no need to search anything. Just create standalone configuration file for that.

**config.vars**

```
# loads by cmd.exe script

aaa=111
"bbb=111 222"
/A ccc=1+1
"ddd=%bbb% & 333"
```

**load_config.bat**

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq eol=# tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("config.vars") do (
  call set %%i
)
```